# Check if item already exists in DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am new to Java and Spring Framework, and I'm learning it by a file upload example. I have a controller for uploading of a file. Before I save anything to DB, I would like to check if the file with the same name already exists and return an error message for it. This is how the controller looks like:

```java
@PostMapping("/file-upload")
public String postFile(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile fileUpload, Authentication authentication, Model model) throws IOException {
    if(fileUpload.isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("success",false);
        model.addAttribute("message","No file selected to upload!");
        return "home";
    }

    if(fileService.getByFilename(fileUpload.getOriginalFilename()) != null) {
        model.addAttribute("success",false);
        model.addAttribute("message","File with that name already exists");
        return "home";
    }

    User user = this.userService.getUser(authentication.getName());
    Integer userId = user.getUserId();
    fileService.createFile(fileUpload, userId);
    model.addAttribute("success",true);
    model.addAttribute("message","New File added successfully!");
    return "home";
}
```

And this is the fileService **getByFilename**  method:

```java
public File getByUsername(String filename) {
    return fileMapper.getByUsername(filename);
}
```

And finally fileMapper **getByFilename**:

```java
@Select("SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE filename = #{filename}")
File getByUsername(String filename);
```

But, when I try to upload a file like that, I get an error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
> status=500). Error attempting to get column 'FILEDATA' from result
> set. Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error
> converting

This is how the table looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILES (
    fileId INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    filename VARCHAR,
    contenttype VARCHAR,
    filesize VARCHAR,
    userid INT,
    filedata BLOB,
    foreign key (userid) references USERS(userid)
);
```

How should I fix this?
Here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/Drax74/nd035-c1-spring-boot-basics-project-starter/tree/master/starter/cloudstorage/src/main/java/com/udacity/jwdnd/course1/cloudstorage).

This is the File class:

```
package com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.model;

public class File {
    private Integer fileId;
    private String filename;
    private String contenttype;
    private Long filesize;
    private byte[] filedata;
    private Integer userid;

    public File(Integer fileId, String filename, String contenttype, Long filesize, byte[] filedata, Integer userid) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.contenttype = contenttype;
        this.filesize = filesize;
        this.filedata = filedata;
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public Integer getFileId() {
        return fileId;
    }

    public void setFileId(Integer fileId) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getContenttype() {
        return contenttype;
    }

    public void setContenttype(String contenttype) {
        this.contenttype = contenttype;
    }

    public Long getFilesize() {
        return filesize;
    }

    public void setFilesize(Long filesize) {
        this.filesize = filesize;
    }

    public byte[] getFiledata() {
        return filedata;
    }

    public void setFiledata(byte[] filedata) {
        this.filedata = filedata;
    }

    public Integer getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(Integer userid) { this.userid = userid; }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. And what is the type of `File`? Is it `java.io.File`, then that is likely the reason of the error: it is not a suitable type to convert to from the database output. Also, have you considered adding a unique constraint on the filename column and just attempting to insert? That would produce an error without having to check first.

Comment: I think `fileService.createFile(fileUpload, userId);` is also relevant code that you need to share here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please, add File class

Comment: I have added File class and the link to the repo

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your table strongly suggests that a single row contains all the data: It does **not** represent a file at all, and there *is no file on your file system*: There is a bunch of binary data in the `filedata` column.

It is not possible to just treat this as a java.io.File object, which is a very light wrapper around a physical file on your file system (really - just check it out, File has one field, of type String, containing a path. That's all it has).

Therefore you just can't do what you want here. You need to find an alternative:

### Save the data to an actual file

This involves having some sort of store on the disk, perhaps a tmp dir, where you explicitly write out all the blob data. You'll need to worry about clearing this stuff out or you're going to grow endless files in there.

### Who cares about files?

Why do you *NEED* a file object? You should build software to be as abstract as seems reasonable at the time, and 'I need a file' is rarely the right level. The right level is usually either 'byte array' or 'InputStream' or something similar. Fix your program's flow so that they need only a byte array or better yet an inputstream and use JDBC's blob functionality to take care of this (I don't actually know how to unlock this using spring; you may have to write some code instead of just an `@Select` annotated method.